# Why in console age is coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, object, methods

```
let object = {
    name : `Rahim`,
    age : 10,
    place : `Delhi`,
    
    details : function(){
             return `The fruit name is ${name}. Color is ${age}`;

    }
}

console.log(object.details());
```

Comment: Because it is, you didn't define any variable named `age`. You may want to try `this.age` instead of `age`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

The `name` and `age` variables that you are calling are not any variables and also they are the elements of the same object. So, you will be needing to use ***`this.name`*** or ***`this.age`***. ***`this`*** basically says the function to get the name and age element from the same object, where the function is located. So you will be needing to update your code like this:

```js
let object = {
    name : `Rahim`,
    age : 10,
    place : `Delhi`,
    
    details : function(){
             return `The fruit name is ${this.name}. Color is ${this.age}`;

    }
}

console.log(object.details());
```

Answer (score -3):

you need to define the `name` and `age` first

```
let age = 10;
let name = 'Rahim';
let object = {
    name : name,
    age : age,
    place : `Delhi`,
    
    details : function(){
             return `The fruit name is ${name}. Color is ${age}`;

    }
}

console.log(object.details());
```

or using `this`

```
let object = {
    name : `Rahim`,
    age : 10,
    place : `Delhi`,
    
    details : function(){
             return `The fruit name is ${this.name}. Color is ${this.age}`;

    }
}

console.log(object.details());
```

[image]